# Not a group by expression Beginner

Tags: sql

Here I have three tables

```
PLAYS {ID_athlete, ID_sport, best_result}

PARTICIPATE {ID_athlete, ID_competition, result}

ISAT {ID_sport, ID_competition}
```

I would like to update the best_result attribute IN PLAYS.

I wrote this but I have the "not a group expression" error.

```
UPDATE  PLAYS   PL
SET     BEST_RESULT =   
(
    SELECT  MAX(RESULT)
    FROM    PARTICIPATE P
    GROUP BY P.ID_ATHLETE, P.ID_COMPETITION
    HAVING  PL.ID_ATHLETE = P.ID_ATHLETE 
        AND P.ID_COMPETITION IN 
    (
        SELECT  ID_COMPETITION
        FROM    ISAT
        WHERE   ID_SPORT = PL.ID_SPORT
    )
)
```

I don't know where my error comes from. I want to get the max result of a certain athlete in a certain sport and put it in best_result.

Comment: Can you put the MAX(Result) in a variable and then update the table using the variable?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I can try to create a procedure and for each record of plays, i put the max(result) in a variable and update the table with it. I'm going to try this ! Thank you :)

Comment: @nivas, I would like to update the best result of each athlete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.  Use a where clause to limit it and take the max. HAVING is for aggregate filters.

```
UPDATE  PLAYS   PL
SET     BEST_RESULT =   
(
    SELECT  MAX(RESULT)
    FROM    PARTICIPATE P
    WHERE   PL.ID_ATHLETE = P.ID_ATHLETE 
    AND P.ID_COMPETITION IN 
    (
        SELECT  ID_COMPETITION
        FROM    ISAT
        WHERE   ID_SPORT = PL.ID_SPORT
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got your `WHERE` and `HAVING` caluses mixed up. For this SQL (getting the max result), you don't even need `GROUP BY` or `HAVING`. Just plain a condition should do the job.

```
UPDATE PLAYS PL
SET BEST_RESULT =   
    (
    SELECT MAX(RESULT)
    FROM PARTICIPATE P
    WHERE PL.ID_ATHLETE = P.ID_ATHLETE 
          AND P.ID_COMPETITION IN 
                                  (SELECT ID_COMPETITION
                                  FROM ISAT
                                  WHERE ID_SPORT = PL.ID_SPORT)
    )
```

Comment: Wow, it was that simple ! Thank you very much. I understand now why I don't even need GROUP BY or HAVING.